# Objective C Server

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection

i was wondering if there is any way i can set up a server in Objective C that sits on a server box.

From what some people have told me the form post action to HTML pages for information or .ASPX Web Services can be slower then an actual server would be.

How could i set up a server program written in objective c that i would send a message to and get a response back.

For example i send the server the string:

Add(2,8);

And i do some string manipulation work on the server to eventually add the two and send back a response of:

10

I know this sounds obscure and the need for this would be unique, but I'm just trying to find a data transfer protocol that responds faster then your everyday HTML Post.

This would help me with games for iPhone that have a much more chatter then slow NSURLConnections would allow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are mixed up on a lot of things.  You don't POST forms to HTML, and ASP.NET web services do run on actual servers.

If I'm understanding you correctly, what you want to avoid is none of that stuff, but rather the overhead with HTTP?  For games, it's common to use UDP, or if you need a more reliable connection, TCP.

What language you implement the server part of your game in is irrelevant - it doesn't have to be Objective-C.

Sending strings that the server has to parse is a bit silly if you're going for efficiency - you should define a packet structure instead of parsing text.  There are some GameKit examples in Apple's developer library that take that approach, you should review them to see how the packets are constructed.

Comment: I understand what you mean in your first to paragraphs i just explained it wrong.

Comment: And the parsing string part is just an example of sending SOMETHING to a server.

Comment: I will review the documents you have specified.

Comment: One minor disagreement here with the answer: I'd go with text-based client/server messages unless there was proof that they were unacceptably slow.  If that proof existed, I'd still keep my text interface and add a binary one.  There are real advantages for development and debugging if you can use something like telnet to trigger server functions and examine responses.